# Detecting QR-Codes in Android ARCore

Tags: android, arcore

I'm trying to setup an Android AR App which should be able to detect QR Codes and, using [Augmented Images](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images), draw simple objects on their location.
Now, I could not find any Information how to add QR Codes into the AugmentedImageDatabase. I could generate images I think (e.g. "qr_code1.jpg"), store it locally and then add it to the database, but that seems inefficient. Also storing every possible QR code we might use on the device seems not efficient as well.

Is there any other way or good practice to use QR codes for Augmented Images? It seems like a basic concept but I just could not find anything to this.

Thanks for any tips

Comment: It appears to not be natively supported. Google has a library for recognizing QR Codes, which may be helpful: https://developers.google.com/vision